# How to filter txt file by string with using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I know this kind of problem will be very easy for you but I am total beginner in batch mode.

The question is how bat file code should look like to generate a new txt file from specific one .

for example .

I have report txt

```
Displaying status for license file: 7788@Server01

License Server: server01

                    License    In Use   Free
                    -------    ------   ----
                    Design*      1       6
                               (user1@host1)   127 server01 7788  4402

                  Assembly*      0       4

                       Pro       0      15

                     AdvSE       2       3
                              (user2@host2)  AdvSE server01 7788  2706
                              (user3@host3)  AdvSE server01 7788  1503

        SingleSite_License       1       3
                              (user4@host4)      SingleSite_License server01 7788  2003

      Intra_CLIENT_License        1       4
                              (user2@host2)      Intra_CLIENT_License server01 7788  2003

                       CAD       1      32
                              ^(user2@host2)     CAD server01 7788   501
* = License Extensions - Available only on startup.
^ = Borrowed License.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What I want to have in new file from this one are only lines :

SingleSite_License 3

Intra_CLIENT_License 9

but both SingleSite_License and Intra_Client_License should be taken from 1st found string -other are not necessary.

report txt can be different and licenses can be showed in different order .

if it not possible - other solution can be just only Free value will be written in new txt file - f.e 3 and 9 . so the last string in line which contains specific words

thank you for any tips

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where you got the figure of `9` for the `Intra_CLIENT_License` (souldn't it be `4`?), but this script will print out the free licences for those two product codes:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,3" %%a in ('type infile.txt') do (
    if "x%%a"=="xSingleSite_License" (
        echo %%a %%b
    )
    if "x%%a"=="xIntra_CLIENT_License" (
        echo %%a %%b
    )
)
endlocal
```

I basically cut and pasted your transcript into the `infile.txt` file and ran this script to get:

```
SingleSite_License 3
Intra_CLIENT_License 4
```

(you can replace `type infile.txt` with whatever command you need to generate that output).

---

*Breakdown:*

The `setlocal` just sets up `cmd.exe` to allow extensions and delayed expansion of environment variables. All my scripts start with this since it's so useful.

The `for` loop basically processes one line at a time, grabbing tokens 1 and 3 (`a` and `b`) from each.

Then it's a simple matter of checking `a` for the required licence values and, if it matches, outputting that along with `b`.

Comment: @Jens, Yes, it was done on XP so should work on all supported versions of Windows. Don't try to backport it to Windows 3.11 :-) Batch has come a long way since the brain-dead days of MSDOS 2.11 - it's still no match for UNIX shells but it's not _too_ bad.

Comment: HI Yes you are right = should be 4 instead of 9 - and first of all thank you for this solution - it works perfectly . now the only problem which left me is to delay the execute of this command . Because at first first script creates report.txt and next filters it as you wrote . I don't know how to combine them because filter searches for file which doesn't exist yet - it needs about 3-5 s and I have no idea how to delay it - I tried "PING -n 4 127.0.0.1>nul " but it doesn't pause

Comment: @Ante, that ping command _should_ wait 3 seconds. Leave off the `>nul` bit and tell me what the output is.

Comment: OK everything seems to ok now . THANK YOU very much for this tip !! best regards

Answer (score 0):

Write a C application. Batch is unnecessarily kludgy and probably can't even do this kind of stream manipulation.

Comment: HI
Yes you are right = should be 4 instead of 9 - and first of all thank you for this solution - it works perfectly . 

now the only problem which left me is to delay the execute of this command . Because at first first script creates report.txt and next filters it as you wrote .  I don't know how to combine them because filter searches for file which doesn't exist yet - it needs about 3-5 s and I have no idea how to delay it - I tried "PING -n 4 127.0.0.1>nul " but it doesn't pause .

Answer (score 0):

Download [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) and use the Unix stream processors. Might be possible to do with Powershell too.